# Organizing & normalising RSS Feed categories data

Tags: sql, database-design, rss, rdbms, database-normalization

I am having trouble normalising data from a RSS Feed into a database.

Each post would have `id` and `categories`.

The problem I am having is that `categories` is a list which is not predefined in size. By 1NF I should split a list up such that each column only has atomic data:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | flying   |
|  2 | swimming |
|  3 | throwing |
|  4 | sleeping |
|  5 | etc      |
+----+----------+
```

However, blog posts can have more than one category tagged. This means that the `posts` table can have a list of ids of the categories tagged.

Alternatively, the `categories` table can have two ids:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | postId |   name   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | flying   |
|  2 |      1 | swimming |
|  3 |      1 | throwing |
|  4 |      2 | flying   |
|  5 |      2 | swimming |
|  6 |      2 | etc      |
+----+--------+----------+
```

And the `posts` table `id` will reference the `postId` column. However, there is repeated data, which is not good.

Lastly, another method I had thought of was to put all the categories in one table:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| id | flying | swimming | throwing | sleeping | etc |
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 |      1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |   1 |
|  2 |      0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |   0 |
|  3 |      1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |   1 |
|  4 |      0 |        0 |        1 |        1 |   1 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

`1`s representing present and `0`s representing absent, the `id` in the `posts` table references `id`. This method would not have any repeated data. However, categories from blogs can be created at will, making it hard to maintain such a table as I would need to update it every time there is a new category.

How do I put my database in 3NF, eliminating repetition while keeping it maintainable?

Comment: You don't clearly explain your tables. Also, don't you mean the "alternate categories table" postId references the Posts table id, not vice versa; and the last table id references the Posts table id, not vice versa? (Maybe rows in both are 1:1 with rows in Posts?) ("References" means "can only ever have values that appear in".) Please: 1. Give every table a unique name. 2. Give a Posts table example. 3. Use "references" in the right direction. 4. Per my answer, for each table *give the predicate (sentence template parmeterized by columns) that is made into a true statement by rows in it*.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** "Repeated data" is a bugbear. Learn about design and normalization. Start with rows/tables that make *clear straightforward relevant statements about an arbitrary situation*. So far all you need is:

```
-- [id] identifies a post with ...
Post(id, ...)
-- post [id] is tagged [name]
Post_Category(id, name)
```

---

> there is repeated data, which is not good

What exactly do you think "repeated data" is? And why exactly do you think it's "not good"?

There is nothing intrinsically bad about having the same value appear multiple times as a column of a row or part of a value for a column of a row. What matters is whether rows in tables say overlapping things about a situation in certain ways.

Normalization replaces a table by projections of it that join back to it. That means that it replaces tables whose rows say (ie have *predicate*) "*some stuff* AND *other stuff*" about column values by tables whose rows say "*some stuff*" and "*other stuff*" separately. Having "AND"s in such a row/table meaning isn't always bad. When there's only one AND, normalization says to decompose to a particular pair of tables exactly when no shared column set always holds a unique set of values in either of the two tables.

> put all the categories in one table

Although there is nothing about such a design that would cause normalization to decompose it, your last table is a "bad" design. (Sometimes this kind of design with repeated similar columns is said to violate some notion of "1NF" or "normalization", but that is a misconception.) Eg its rows say "(post [id] is tagged 'flying' and [flying] = 1 OR post [id] is not tagged 'flying' AND [flying] = 0) AND (post [id] is tagged 'swimming' and [swimming] = 1 OR post [id] is not tagged 'swimming' AND [swimming] = 0) AND ..." when instead we could just have a table Post_Category with rows saying "post [id] is tagged [name]". Eg we cannot write queries that ask about all categories without mentioning all categories explicitly. Eg if we add a new category then we must add a new column to the table and then if we want our past queries re all categories to mean the same thing then they we must add the new column to still be referring to all categories.

PS It's not clear why you introduced ids. There are reasons we do so, but you should do it *for* a reason. (Normalization does not introduce ids.) Eg introducing post ids if posts are not uniquely identifiable by other information we want to record.

Comment: Could you rephrase your answer and explain your examples in the second part? What is it that I should do?

Comment: See my edited post. There were some errors in my predicates, but I just lopped that (inessential) part out.